# chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow callback returns an undefined redirect_url

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm dealing with a very gnarly Chrome extension auth problem ("Authorization page could not be loaded."). For context, the version of my plugin that was released to the Chrome store is not having these auth problems, it's only my local copy that is running into this issue.

I set up my back-end app to do FB OAuth2. I correctly handle FB sign-in, and redirect to "https://.chromiumapp.org/#authentication_token=#{auth_token}&email=#{email}". This is when the bug occurs. In my production extension, I extract the auth token from the redirect_url (standard) and embed it into the extension. In my development extension (which has identical code), the callback has an undefined redirect_url (the first argument in the callback function). Below is the logic:

```
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
  {'url': requestUrl, 'interactive': true},
  function(redirect_url) {
    if (redirect_url) {
      var queryString = redirect_url.split(/[\#\&]/);
      if (queryString.length > 1) {
        window.tokens = queryString.slice(1).map(function(token){
          return token.split('=')[1];
        });
    }
    var authToken = tokens[0];
    var email = tokens[1];
    if (authToken) {
      ...

    } else {
      ...
    }
  }
);
```

In the above code, `redirect_url` is returning as undefined. What could be causing this to be undefined? There MUST be some redirect_url present, or the callback wouldn't even run. What's going on here?

Comment: Is your extension id the same?

Comment: I think that's it! It seems the new development app has a new client id

Comment: Confirmed that the new version has a different client id; thanks a ton

Comment: How is the extension id related to the problem? I'm facing the same issue, but I don't see the extension id being used anywhere.